# How to upload one photo to two different locations with different size

Tags: php, file-upload

Okay so I have this code to upload photos on my page:

```
        $filename   = uniqid() . "_" . time(); // 5dab1961e93a7_1571494241
        $extension  = pathinfo( $_FILES["post_image"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION ); // jpg
        $basename   = $filename . '.' . $extension; // 5dab1961e93a7_1571494241.jpg
        $target_dir = "../postimages/";
        $target_file = $target_dir . $basename;
        $uploadOk = 1;
        $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        $file_name = $_FILES['post_image']['tmp_name'];
        $maxDim = 1080;

        if($_FILES['post_image']['tmp_name']=='') {
            $image = "noimage.png";
} else {$check = getimagesize($_FILES["post_image"]["tmp_name"]);
                if($check !== false) {
                    $uploadOk = 1;
                } else {
                    echo "File is not an image.";
                    $uploadOk = 0;
                }

            // Check if file already exists
            if (file_exists($target_file)) {
                echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
                $uploadOk = 0;
            }
            // Check file size
            if ($_FILES["post_image"]["size"] > 5000000000) {
                echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
                $uploadOk = 0;
            }
            // Allow certain file formats
            if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
            && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
                echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
                $uploadOk = 0;
            }
            // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
            if ($uploadOk == 0) {
                echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
            // if everything is ok, try to upload file
            } else {
                list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize( $file_name );
            if ( $width > $maxDim || $height > $maxDim ) {
            $target_filename = $file_name;
            $ratio = $width/$height;
            if( $ratio > 1) {
                $new_width = $maxDim;
                $new_height = $maxDim/$ratio;
            } else {
                $new_width = $maxDim*$ratio;
                $new_height = $maxDim;
            }
                $src = imagecreatefromstring( file_get_contents( $file_name ) );
                $dst = imagecreatetruecolor( $new_width, $new_height );
                imagecopyresampled( $dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height );
                imagedestroy( $src );
                imagepng( $dst, $target_filename ); // adjust format as needed
                imagedestroy( $dst );
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["post_image"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
                } else {
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["post_image"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
                }      
            }
        }
```

This code works perfect to upload one photo to one folder, but I would like to upload one copy of the photo but with a smaller dimensions to a *thumbnail* folder. Anyone got any good idea on how I would do that?

Comment: Are you deliberately avoiding the 2nd param of `uniqid()` because of the dot that it generates?

Comment: @mickmackusa I'm sorry, I'm not sure of what dot you talk about, I'm very new to this.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/Stgd2 and https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

Comment: @mickmackusa Do you suggest I should use the 2nd param? And do you got any solution to my question? I really can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: I don't have time to delve into your question.  I just wanted to make you aware of the utility of `uniqid()` -- but that said, you might not want to use the feature because it generates a dot in the file name that does not immediately precede the extension.